# getting a list of dictionaries as a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Ok so I have a list of the same dictionaries and I want to get the values of the dictionaries into a list of lists. For example this is what one dictionary might look like:

`mylist = [{'a': 0, 'b': 2},{'a':1, 'b':3}]`

I want the lists of lists to look like:

`[[0,2],[1,3]]`

I have tried doing

`zip(*[d.values() for d in mylist])`

however this results in a list of different keys for example:

`[[0,1],[2,3]]`

Comment: Just remove the `zip`, you did it then went a step too far

Comment: Using `zip` like this is a common idiom for transposing a matrix represented as a list of lists. You just want the matrix.

Comment: `[list(d.values()) for d in mylist]` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, I don't think you need `zip()` for this to work, instead just try something simpler such as `[list(i.values()) for i in mylist]`
You convert the values into a list with the `list()` function, and the values are already obtained with the `.values()` method

Comment: Thanks for all the help didn't realize I had complicated it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `[list(i.values()) for i in mylist]`